# Swift Firebase Ios User Defined Child Value

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I want to create child id from text input when user register.
[image]

[image]

how to change chidbyautoid to a user input id

Comment: Please include your code and datastructure as text instead of an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

self.ref.child("users").child((Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!).setValue(["username": fname])

This Works Fine

Answer (score 0):

Just use `self.ref.child("users").child(user.uid).setValue(["username": fname])`. 
Replace `user.uid` with your custom user input.

Comment: self.ref.child("users").child((Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!).setValue(["username": fname])

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var username = [String:AnyObject]()
username["username"] = usernametextfield!.text  //outlet of username textfield 
var userinput = userinputtextfield!.text       //outlet of input textfield     

self.ref.child("users").child("\(userinputid)").setvalue(username)
```